# restarting a View from inside child class

Tags: android, view

My question is maybe a bit dumb but can you give me some advice of how I solve the following thing most efficiently:
I have an Activity which holds a Frame layout and to this are some Views attached.
One of these Views (is a SurfaceView and) runs some graphical code while this graphic are drawn and updated from another Thread. Once a certain action is perfromed on this View/Thread I want to replace the old SurfaceView with a new one (basicly restarting the darwing without instanciating the whole new activity). I hope you can help me because Im quit lost xD
(P.S. I have a runOnUiThread to handle the action of replacement)

If you dont understand what Im trying to accomplish feel free to ask.
Thanks for your help ;)

Edit: Graph of my codeflow (If youll need it more specific ill send some actual code)
[image: Graph of my codeflow]

Edit2:
Code:

```
public class GameActivity extends Activity{
FrameLayout game;
Game g;
View deathscreen;

public void onCreate(Vundle savedInstanceState){
 game = new FrameLayout(this);
 g = new Game(this);
 deathscreen = LayoutInfalter.from(this).inflate(R.layout.deathscreen, 
null);

 game.addView(deathScreen);
 game.addView(g);
 setContentView(game);
}
public void restartGame(){
 g = new Game(this);
}
}

Game.java{
 Player p;
 GameThread gt;

 public void surfaceCreated(){
  player = new Player();
  gt = new GameThread();
 }
}

GameThread.java extends Thread:
 Game g; //ref to Game instance
 public void run(){

 while(a){
  //lock canvas
  g.update();  //calling Player.update();
  g.draw(canvas);
 } 
}

Player.java:
GameActivity g;
[...]
public void update(){
 if(...){
  g.restartGame();
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try reinflating your layout and setting it using setContentView(view). This may work or may not work depending on how the rest of your code is set up

Comment: I aint sure what u mean but when i try to make another instance of my "Game" Object (which extends from a surfaceView and has no layout) the SurfaceView simply freezes

Comment: well it has a layout but its empty thou

Comment: added a graph in my question

Comment: I'm afraid I'll need to see the code. Without it it's not clear where you are creating the SurfaceView.

Comment: i hope its usefull

Comment: Move all of your code that's in onCreate into restartGame. Then call restartGame in onCreate.

Comment: Works like a charm. Thought about that but thought it would be as slow as creating another activity. Thanks m8 ;)

Comment: No worries  Good luck with your game!